# OAuth 2, cant send the mail exception

Tags: java, oauth, gmail

I'm trying to send a mail with oauth 2 token, I already have it but when I'm going to send the mail it simply doesn't work.

I'm getting the following:

```
 {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
```

This is the line that is not working:

```
 SMTPTransport smtpTransport = connectToSmtp("smtp.gmail.com", 587, user, oauthToken, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the token like this:

```
String authURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=email&"
```

I changed the "email" for this:

```
String authURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://mail.google.com/%20profile&"
```

I hope this help someone